# Infinite Series for the $x$ coordinate of the $n^{\text{th}}$ peak/valley of $\text{cosc}(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, trigonometry

The [Sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) gives this infinite series for the $x$ coordinate of the $n^{\text{th}}$ peak/valley as:
$$
x(n) = q(n) - q(n)^{-1} - \frac{2}{3}q(n)^{-3} - \frac{13}{15}q(n)^{-5}-\frac{146}{105}q(n)^{-7}...
$$
where
$$
q(n) = \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi
$$
which is way easier to use than having to repeatedly solve for where the derivative is zero:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\text{sinc}(x) = \frac{\cos(x)-\text{sinc}(x)}{x} = 0
$$
which is where:
$$
\cos(x) = \text{sinc}(x)
$$
**Unfortunately**, Wikipedia doesn't have an equivalent page for the $\text{cosc}$ function, so I need to derive the equivalent for ${\cos(x)}/{x}$ myself... sigh.  Worse, I don't know *how* they derived the infinite series above (I'd actually like the next term in that series for a touch more precision).

What I do know is that the derivative will be zero:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\text{cosc}(x) = \frac{\sin(x)-\text{cosc}(x)}{x} = 0
$$
which is where:
$$
\sin(x) = \text{cosc}(x)
$$
and I know that the $q(n)$ will be:
$$
q(n) = n\pi
$$
where the odd $n$'s are valleys and the even $n$'s are peaks (for positive values of $x$); so, each valley will be a little before $\pi, 3\pi, 5\pi,$ etc, and each peak will be a little before $2\pi, 4\pi, 6\pi$, etc.

I am guessing that I cannot use the same infinite series for $x(n)$, but perhaps I can?  Anyone know how they got the infinite series for $\text{sinc}$ or how to get the infinite series for $\text{cosc}$??

Comment: I just wanted to point out that $\cos x/x$ is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is basically the same as for $\text{sinc}(x)$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\text{cosc}(x) = -\frac{x \sin (x)+\cos (x)}{x^2} = 0$$ (you have a sign error in your post).

So, the idea is to make a series expansion of $x \sin (x)+\cos (x)$ around $x=n \pi$ and perform a series resversion. Using $q=n\pi$, this gives
$$x_n=q-\frac{1}{q}-\frac{2}{3 q^3}-\frac{13}{15 q^5}-\frac{146}{105 q^7}-\frac{781}{315
   q^9}-\frac{378193}{80640 q^{11}}-\frac{1043207}{120960 q^{13}}-\frac{77363}{5760
   q^{15}}+\cdots$$

Checking

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 2.7983867501891801260 &  2.7983860457838871367 \\
 2 & 6.1212504669728075585 &  6.1212504668980683013 \\
 3 & 9.3178664617916658477 &  9.3178664617910653790 \\
 4 & 12.486454395223803464 &  12.486454395223781428 \\
 5 & 15.644128370333029398 &  15.644128370333027630 \\
 6 & 18.796404366210157398 &  18.796404366210157169 \\
 7 & 21.945612879981044614 &  21.945612879981044573 \\
 8 & 25.092910412112097369 &  25.092910412112097360 \\
 9 & 28.238936575260272932 &  28.238936575260272929 \\
 10 & 31.384074017889858489 &  31.384074017889858488
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: (+1) Beat me to it! As a quick point for OP, we expand around $n \pi$ because we're trying to solve $\sin(x) + \frac{\cos(x)}{x} = 0$. But $\frac{\cos(x)}{x} \approx 0$, so we need $\sin(x) \approx 0$ too. This happens when $x \approx n \pi$, so we taylor expand there.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor. For once, the old man won ! Cheers :-)